# Script files aren't included in page when changing pages

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I moved from one page to another and the script files don't show up in when I view the files in Chrome's F12.

This is how it looks on that page:

[image]

And this is on the previous page:

[image]

Both have the same includes.

I moved to that page using: `window.location.pathname = '/' + responseJson.redirect;` could it be the reason for it to not load the script files? What other reason there could be?

Edit2: I changed it to `document.location.href =  responseJson.redirect;` and now the scripts and CSS show up, but why?